# Change standard voicemail prompts names in asterisk

Tags: asterisk, voicemail

is it possible to put my own voicemail prompts in asterisk voicemail? I have them but I must rename all of them like `vm-...` If they are not `vm-...` asterisk plays `en` voices..

I made another directory and put `CHANNEL(language)=...` in my dialplan.